# How do I do a boolean string comparison in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

In simple terms I want to add the contents of some columns together but only if the associated columns contain a specific value. To do this in MS Access I use the following:

```
STRUint:(Abs(1*([Code01]='0192'))*[Code01int])+(Abs(1*([Code02]='0192'))*[Code02int])...
```

Breaking this down, if Code01='0192' I get the result TRUE which I multiply by 1 to get -1 and use Abs to convert to 1. This is then multiplied by Code01int, so I'd have an integer equal to Code01int only when Code01 was '0192' otherwise I'd have zero. The result of that calculation is added to the next calculation in the sequence and so on.

The sequence is repeated 15 times adding together the integers in Code01int through Code15int where the content of Code01 through Code15 is '0192'

The only way I personally can think how to do this in SQL is with

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET STRUint = 0

UPDATE Table1 
SET STRUint = CASE 
                 WHEN Code01='0192' THEN STRUint + Code01int 
              END

UPDATE Table1 
SET STRUint = CASE 
                 WHEN Code02='0192' THEN STRUint + Code02int 
              END
etc
```

Is this the only way to achieve my goal, by doing many UPDATEs? I do this for 15 sets of columns and repeat for different string content 5 times, so 80 updates (including the initial set to zero).

I'm hoping there's a way to do this without so many updates on the assumption that it's better to not do so many.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: @ZoharPeled, are you asking me to edit my question and include CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements to give example of my data?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This will enable whoever tries to answer the question to copy your sample data to a test environment.

Comment: @Lawrence In my answer I did this for you. The goal is a *stand-alone* sample to reproduce your problem, a so called [mcve].

Comment: It occurs to me that where I mentioned how I was trying to solve my question I may have mislead people with what I was asking; is there a concept of Boolean expression in SQL? e.g. 'X'='Y' should return FALSE or 9 > 5 should return TRUE. Certainly the answers given achieve the same end results, from my programming days back in the 80's I learnt Boolean was faster than IF..THEN..ELSE. That may not be the case these days in which case I should forget about using Boolean.

Comment: @Lawrence, comments are not the best place for this discussion. Just in short: SQL-Server does not know the datatype `BOOLEAN`. There is `BIT`, which is an `INT` restricted to `0` or `1`. An expression can be *evaluated to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. In general, it is up to the (very good) engine to decide, how things are processed. Quite often this is not the way you would expect it to be. In your case the expensive part is not the computation, but the `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET STRUint = 0;

UPDATE 
    Table1 
SET 
    STRUint += 
    CASE WHEN Code01='0192' THEN Code01int ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN Code02='0192' THEN Code02int ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN Code03='0192' THEN Code03int ELSE 0 END
etc.
```

Comment: Thank you Richard, I didn't know `+=` was a thing in SQL and it never occurred to me to string a sequence of CASE statements together like that.

Answer (score 2):

Best was to change your table's design. Whenever you feel the need to *name-number* columns (such as `Code01`, `Code02`) you should rather use a related side table.

My code will use `APPLY` with `VALUES()` to create the needed structure on the fly (kind of *unpivoting*) and then `GROUP BY` and `SUM()` to get what (I think) you are asking for.

```
DECLARE @MockTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY
                        ,Comment VARCHAR(100)
                        ,Code01 VARCHAR(100),Code01int INT
                        ,Code02 VARCHAR(100),Code02int INT
                        ,Code03 VARCHAR(100),Code03int INT);
INSERT INTO @MockTable VALUES('One is a' ,'a',1,'b',1,'c',1)
                            ,('All are a','a',1,'a',1,'a',1)
                            ,('Two are a','b',1,'a',1,'a',1);
```

--I use 'a' instead of your number, but you'll get the ghist

```
DECLARE @SearchCode VARCHAR(100)='a';
```

--The query

```
SELECT t.ID
      ,t.Comment
      ,SUM(A.Val) AS SumOfValuesForTheCode
FROM @MockTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1,Code01,Code01int)
                  ,(2,Code02,Code02int)
                  ,(3,Code03,Code03int))A(Indx,Code,Val)
WHERE A.Code=@SearchCode
GROUP BY t.ID,t.Comment
```

The result

```
1   One is a    1
2   All are a   3
3   Two are a   2
```

### UPDATE: Fully generic approach:

This won't be fast, but it is - in a way - beautiful :-)

```
SELECT t.ID 
      ,t.Comment 
      ,RowAsXml.query('for $code in /row/*[string-length(local-name())=6 
                                           and substring(local-name(),1,4)="Code" 
                                           and text()=sql:variable("@SearchCode")]
                       return /row/*[local-name()=concat(local-name($code),"int")]')
               .value('sum(*/text())','int')
FROM @MockTable t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH('row'),TYPE) A(RowAsXml)
```

The idea in short:

The `APPLY` will create a XML representing the entire row. Against this XML we can use XQuery's FLWOR. The given xquery will run through the nodes and find those, where the name's length is 6 and which start with "Code" and where the `text()` (= the content) is equal to the value you are looking for.

Knowing the fitting code nodes, we can return the fitting value nodes by conactenating the column name with the word "int".

With this we can build a sum, voila!

The intermediate XML looks like this (one per row)

```
<row>
  <Comment>One is a</Comment>
  <Code01>a</Code01>
  <Code01int>1</Code01int>
  <Code02>b</Code02>
  <Code02int>1</Code02int>
  <Code03>c</Code03>
  <Code03int>1</Code03int>
</row>
```

### UPDATE: How to update a table's column

You might use a joined query like here

```
DECLARE @MockTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY
                        ,Comment VARCHAR(100)
                        ,Code01 VARCHAR(100),Code01int INT
                        ,Code02 VARCHAR(100),Code02int INT
                        ,Code03 VARCHAR(100),Code03int INT
                        ,STRUint INT);
INSERT INTO @MockTable(Comment,Code01,Code01int,Code02,Code02int,Code03,Code03int) 
                       VALUES('One is a' ,'a',1,'b',1,'c',1)
                            ,('All are a','a',1,'a',1,'a',1)
                            ,('Two are a','b',1,'a',1,'a',1);

DECLARE @SearchCode VARCHAR(100)='a';

UPDATE t1 SET STRUint=t2.SumOfValuesForTheCode
FROM
@MockTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.ID
          ,t.Comment
          ,SUM(A.Val) AS SumOfValuesForTheCode
    FROM @MockTable t
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1,Code01,Code01int)
                      ,(2,Code02,Code02int)
                      ,(3,Code03,Code03int))A(Indx,Code,Val)
    WHERE A.Code=@SearchCode
    GROUP BY t.ID,t.Comment
) t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID;
```

--Check the result

```
SELECT * FROM @MockTable
```

Another approach uses an *updateable CTE*

```
WITH FindValue AS
(
    SELECT t.ID
          ,SUM(A.Val) AS SumOfValuesForTheCode
    FROM @MockTable t
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1,Code01,Code01int)
                      ,(2,Code02,Code02int)
                      ,(3,Code03,Code03int))A(Indx,Code,Val)
    WHERE A.Code=@SearchCode
    GROUP BY t.ID,t.Comment
)
,TargetTable AS
(
    SELECT t1.STRUint
          ,t2.SumOfValuesForTheCode 
    FROM @MockTable t1 
    INNER JOIN FindValue t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
)
UPDATE TargetTable SET STRUint=SumOfValuesForTheCode;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer Shnugo. The table design is not mine and cannot be changed, it meets the design specification for another purpose, and I agree with you. The two answers you've provided give the results I would expect. How do I wrap the UPDATE statement around that?

Comment: @Lawrence See my answer. Both approach you find there will work with both approaches to compute the value.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I attempted an UPDATE myself but went wrong somewhere, using your code worked fine for me. I now have a dilemma because all three answers here work and I need to pick just one :(  I'm tempted to pick an answer that looks the simplest to me but worry I may be breaking rules or etiquette here.

Comment: @Lawrence Which answer you choose is up to you... No problem with that. Happy coding...

Comment: @Lawrence One tiny hint: It is up to you, which answer you choose, but you are asked to choose one in order to close this question. Thx

Answer (score 1):

do you have any ID in the table?
if yes you can do:

```
UPDATE A
SET STRUint = B.TOTAL
FROM TABLE1 A
     INNER JOIN
     (
      SELECT ID,SUM(VALUE) AS TOTAL
      FROM
      (
        SELECT ID,Code01int AS VALUE
        FROM TABLE
        WHERE Code01= '0192' 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID,Code02int
        FROM TABLE
        WHERE Code02= '0192' 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID,Code03int
        FROM TABLE
        WHERE Code03= '0192' 
        ....
        ....
      )A
      GROUP BY ID
    )B
    ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: Thanks Danny, that does indeed give the results I would expect.